# Places LEAST likely to be looted in an Apocalypse

Tags: society, post-apocalypse

In an pist appacolyptic earth quake zombie infection, what places that might be over looked in the first 3 week by looters and survivors?

Big places such as Walmarts and Costco's are bound to be looted down to the shelves being stripped. I am looking for a few places that average people might not flock to cuz they are going to the gun store and sports store instead or might not even know they exist.

For example an amazon shipping center those places literally have everything you could ever need for YEARS but it's not something people think about right away. They are to busy heading as states for places people the average people know of.

Comment: This seems pretty open-ended. Could you add more details?

Comment: McMurdo station, ISS.

Comment: Large ocean going ships in port - fuel, food, water, medicines and ease of zombie avoidance by drawing up the gang plank

Comment: @Slarty That's a good idea. Relatedly, small ships (ferries), trains, and planes should all have individually wrapped snacks, presumably packaged for long term storage (well, they don't seem very fresh at least). Of course, these locations are likely to have been zombified early as transit centers, but they might have been missed in the early looting waves as a result, since the zombies were coming from them.

Answer (score 24):

## There isn't anything people won't loot

> Oh look, a sign for a dentist office. Let's check it out.

You have to understand that whether or not people loot a dentist office has nothing to do with having thought of it...simply seeing one along their travels will be enough for them to loot it.

People will see a location, and then think about whether that location will have useful resources. They usually won't say "Let's go find a dentist office." because in this zombie-ridden world, finding loot will be all about utilizing the resources around you.

> Oh look, an elementary school. Let's check it out.

And then upon checking it out, they find the nurse's office and also loot the cafeteria.

> Oh look, a ship. Let's check it out.

#### People will always search what they can.

Not only that, but any place that can be used as shelter from the weather or zombies will also be searched while they wait. When in a dangerous situation, people will simply run to the closest building. This means that there aren't really any locations that are more or less likely to be safe from looting.

---

However:

## Think about what people *won't* search:

- Certain animals may hide food in discrete locations; one of your characters may have knowledge of this animal that most people don't have.
- Underwater; perhaps one of your characters has knowledge of tides and ocean currents, and can pinpoint a location where most shipwrecked resources would end up
- Historical knowledge; perhaps one of your characters knows that secret compartments were often installed in old cabinets from the 1950s, and is able to find a hidden stash.
- The rest is up to you; this is your world. You can write it however you want!

Comment: People are more likely to loot artificial facilities. Shops, buildings, schools etc. These days they're perhaps less likely to "loot" the natural world, i.e. go foraging in the remote forests / outback. Partly because the density of useful supplies is much greater in shops etc. but also because the knowledge to survive in the wild isn't there in this generation to the same degree that it was in the past. That mushroom, is it food or deadly? Those berries? Good idea?  So your characters' best bet might be to take a chance in the wilds. Also perhaps less pop density => fewer zombies.

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer. Think about the way most people play RPGs: if they *can* enter a building, they *will* enter the building, and then steal everything that's not nailed down.

Answer (score 12):

**Nests of zombies.**

1. If there are a lot of zombies, before that they were a lot of people.
2. If there were a lot of people in one place, they had supplies for a lot of people.
3. Once the people turn into zombies, they wont use the supplies.
4. The presence of hundreds of zombies will dissuade casual looters.

Likely zombie nests will be schools, refugee camps, sports arenas or other places that were set up as public shelters during the early part of the apocalypse.  Or strongholds that the looters set up before they all went zombie - most of the stuff they looted from Kmart will still be there with them.

Also this will be more exciting for your story than having your characters loot an abandoned nursing home.

Comment: Funny you should say that in my story the first place they loot IS a Nursong home xD

Comment: For a story to be interesting, there needs to be moments that are boring and calm in order for the exciting moments to truly stand out. I think an abandoned nursing home is a fantastic idea; you can catch the reader off guard and get them hooked by suddenly plunging them into excitement and disarray.

Comment: Also, people will generally only take huge risks like trying to loot a zombie nest when they have no other choice. Otherwise, they will simply move on and try searching somewhere that feels safer.

Comment: How dangerous a zombie nest is depends on the zombies and on your weapons.  Look at John Ringo's zombie novels--tons of assaulting zombie nests.

Answer (score 4):

**Geocaches**.

It's a weird sport-ish thing, but geocaches are specific buried caches which people who geocache locate. The way it works is that the players find them, take what's in them, and replace with items of equal value. If one of the survivors is a geocacher, he might have a list of them, which equate to buried treasure for your survivors.

Comment: I like the idea, but how many of those geocaches contain *useful* stuff? I thought they mostly contained random junk for the sport of it.

Comment: They do IRL, sure. But in fiction they can contain a lot more valuable items - the point here is that this is a plausible place that won't be searched.

Answer (score 4):

Any place that doesn’t have anything loot-able won’t be looted.  Like a desert island, won’t be looted at all because there is no one to loot it and nothing defined as loot on an island.

Being the humans are such clever creatures, the pinnacle of survivorship in a fierce animal kingdom, one would imagine that hungry and cold humans would rove like locusts looking for anything they could turn into a weapon, eat, or use for clothing or shelter.

The only two things that I can imagine that wouldn’t be looted would things that require detailed knowledge to be turned into one of things on the previous list.  So some chemicals that don’t have an immediate use but are precursors to chemical compounds might be left untouched.  Especially if the first looters accidentally poisoned themselves and their bodies lay in front of the vats of chemicals.

The other kind of that might not be looted are things so frightening and deadly that no one in. their sane mind would go near them.  Like things in the core of a nuclear reactor will most likely be left alone.

And there is one more thing that can’t be looted, things people can’t find — hidden safe rooms or secret underground bases.

Answer (score 3):

## **Other survivor's loot**

Why spend time looking in ambiguous places that might have supplies left over from before the apocalypse when you could just benefit from other people's effort?

They're not likely to be looted as they would only have been gathered in the weeks after the apocalypse.

There's a 50:50 chance they're already dead, in which case it's free real estate. If they're still alive, then that's a moral dilemma that's up to your group to handle....

[Edit] I realise I didn't actually suggest any physical locations these might be in!

The classic starting points would be to follow the passage of people from the start of the collapse - depending on how it all started in your world, people would likely be gathered by the government/military into refugee camps in order to protect them after cities become swarmed by the undead. These would likely have the best variety of supplies, as the government would have used the last of its coordination to stock them.

After that, it gets harder to specifically say where people may set up camp, or what level of supplies they'd be able to find. The longer term the settlement, the higher the chances of them having worthwhile supplies. If your survivors see anywhere fortified, there's a good chance the people who were/are in there have/had stuff worth staying there for.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! While we do appreciate inventive and out-of-the-box thinking, we do aim to produce answers that answer the question as asked. This one seems to want to know where the characters should search for supplies. Your answer only works if the characters know where other survivors holed up. Can you include a way to find such locations? Please don't take the criticism as a reason not to post to the site... we critique all answers and frequently ask for edits, all in the name of getting our questions the best answers possible. Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what they are looking for.
I'd imagine a library as a place not likely to be looted at all.
But anyway here is a couple of things I can think of.

- Cinemas. I do believe they have food. Candy bars, soda, chips...etc are all food and have a long expiry date.
- Vet clinics. A lot of medicine and medical equipment.
- Med schools. They are bound to have important stuff.
- Pet shops. Perhaps pet food is not the tastiest thing ever, but at least it's better than green leaves.
- Food factories, food warehouses, distribution centers...etc.
  This is kind of the jackpot really.
  If you can track down a warehouse for a food company then you can be looking at tons and tons of food. Incredibly useful especially if it's canned food.
- Restaurants. Kitchens should have some supplies. Especially frozen food.
- Airports. 
  If they are not locked down or destroyed or whatever. They would have a lot of stuff.

Comment: I always had this idea that if I could, I would make a library my hideout. Without wikipedia, books are the only source of how-tos for medicines, equipment and farming.

Comment: @TomášZato,
Unless it's a castle mansion type of library with strong wall an a bit far from other stuff then sure.
Unfortunately that would be rare.

Comment: Check out [Czech National Technical Library](https://www.techlib.cz/public/gallery/d7badbb13c7063312afe5b056958a411_resized.jpg). Single stairway entrance observable from all the balconies, solid concrete, modern structure that keeps it's heat in winter. Also, right next to university buildings full of tool and heavy machinery.